# Planned Add-in availability in OWA for Shared Mailboxes

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Can anyone at Microsoft give an update on the planning of releasing of Add-in availability in OWA for Shared Mailboxes? It has been the feature with the highest number of request on UserVoice (http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/11634318-support-for-shared-mailboxes), but that platform does not appear very active.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the OWA beta? While Shared Mailbox support is not yet available, we are focusing on bringing new features including Shared Mailbox support to this version of OWA. We do not have an ETA to share regarding this feature yet but as stated in UserVoice it is currently in our backlog.

Comment: Thanks! Not using OWA beta yet at that still lacks OnSend-support as I know, but would be happy to switch it that and Shared Mailbox Support is available; any indication whether that would be Q1 of Q2 2019? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately we can't give any ETAs for this feature. We *will* however update the UserVoice entry when it is available, so vote/follow that suggestion and you should be able to see when the feature is available in the OWA beta.